# Trouble distributing Python library using ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-management, pypi

I'm attempting to distribute a Python library that dynamically loads a shared object file using `ctypes`. The shared object file was created using Golang. I have a simple `main.go` file that performs some network requests on a few links that are passed, and `.so` & `.h` files built from that.I followed these instructions for compiling the header & shared object file: https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf

The current library structure is 
cwd (current working directory)

- `cwd/display_status/display_status.py`
- `cwd/display_status/__init__.py`
- `cwd/display_status/display_status.h`
- `cwd/display_status/display_status.so`
- `cwd/display_status/main.go`

`display_status.py` is working correctly when ran directly `pyhton3 display_status.py` but when I upload the library to PyPI and try to `import display_status`, I get this error.

`ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_display_status)`

I've tried various settings provided by https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to no avail.

My current setup is

```py
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

# The directory containing this file
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

# The text of the README file
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

module1 = Extension('display_status', sources=['main.go'])
# This call to setup() does all the work
setup(
    name="display_status",
    version="1.0.11",
    description="Displays the status of links",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/KingAkeem/display_status",
    author="Akeem King",
    author_email="akeemtlking@gmail.com",
    license="GNU GPLv3",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser General Public License v3 (LGPLv3)",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    ],
    packages=['display_status'],
    package_data=find_packages(),
    """
    package_data={
        'display_status':
        [
            'main.go',
            'display_status.h',
            'display_status.so'
        ]
    },
    """
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to have a .py and a .so file with the same name and even in the same directory.

Comment: So what would be a better structure?

Comment: Simply rename the .so, e. g. append a "_bin" or something.

Comment: Will this solve the issue?